# Why Lord Ram is called Maryada Purshottam and Lord Krishna Purna Purshottam?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, avatars

I have heard many people saying **Lord Ram is Maryada Purshottam and Lord Krishna is Purna Purshottam**.

Could any one please tell me why is it so. and what is the difference between **Maryada Purshottam and Purna Purshottam**

Comment: rAma is also vigrahavAn dharmaH. The 1st few ramayana slokas list the enormous number of divine qualities of rama. Why he is maryada purushottam while Krishna is referred to as purna purusha has to do with the avataras' visesha (particularity) and purpose. Rama's avatara was to lead by example in the path of dharma. Dharma has boundaries at every stage and every aspect of life- conduct(how to be),action (what to do), speech (what to say and how to speak) etc. Since everything that rama did and said adhered to these maryadAs(rules) that are supreme for humans, he is a maryada purushottama. 1/2

Comment: Krishna did not confine himself to the limitations of a human life. He demonstrated his divine nature and capabilities unhesitatingly and in all their glory. Krishna's avatara visesha is the fullness of divinity. Hence he is purna purusha. This is not to say that Krishna did not respect dharma. He did. But his observance of dharma is an underlying thread and superhuman feats are the highlight.   2/2

Comment: @moonstar2001 Thank you for answering my question. I got it about Lord Ram but could u please give more information on Lord Krishna as purna purshottam.

Comment: The Supreme is said to have 16 kalas. There is a theory that Rama was born with 12 kalas and the remaining 4 were lakshmana,bharata,satrughna & parasurama. Krishna OTOH descended with all 16.So Krishna is purna.This is not to say Rama was incomplete. His remaining kalas existed outside his form.Lakshmana, several times tells Rama that he is his "bahirprANa"(Rama's life-force that resides outside Rama's body). Bhagavatam extolls Krishna as "bhagavAn swayam" which is another testament that Krishna displayed all the glory of the supreme. Pl let me know if you want further elaboration.

Comment: @moonstar2001 If you have more elaboration I would like to have it.

Comment: Rama is the embodiment of the human mind. He is the idol of limitation and dharma. As is the norm, every time a norm is established, the lord breaks it, to establish a new one. The norm of Rama's Dharma had to be replaced by Krishna's Karma. This is exactly why Bhishma [an embodiment of Rama's Dharma in the Mahabharata] and Yudhisthira, both are not chosen as Krishna's disciple but Arjuna- for he is most malleable for change.

Answer (score 2):

Saying shri krishna is purna purushottam but shri ram is just maryada purushottam is injustice

**न रामरूपादीनां केवलं स्त्रीपुरुषाणामेव दृष्टिचित्तापहारकत्वमुपपद्यते किंतु स्थावरजंगमात्मकस्य सर्वं जगतोऽपि ॥ श्रीकृष्णस्तु वेणुरणनैः स्त्रियादिमोहनः ।अयं तु स्वसौन्दर्येण स्त्रिपुं साधारण सर्वजन्तुमोहकः ॥**

[Sundarmani-Sandarbh by shri ramanand sampradaya Rasikacharya  Sri Madhuracharya]

"Sri Krsna is an enchanter of #only_women, and that too with the help of His #flute; but this RAma, with just His natural beauty, enchants #women, #men, and even  #animals also! He doesn't #need_any_flute.”

**दशावतारमव्येऽपि रामकृष्णौ महत्तमौ।
ताभ्ग्रामपि वरः पुर्वः सत्यसंधो रघुत्तमः।।**

(~#श्रीमद्वाल्मीकि_आनंद_रामायण)

दस अवतारों में से श्रीरामचन्द्र तथा कृष्ण श्रेष्ठ है और उन दोनों में श्रीरामचन्द्र सर्वश्रेष्ठ।

Among ten avtars of vishnu, both shri Ramchandra and Krishna are great and among these two, bhagwan shri Ramchandra is the greatest because he has param madhurya, param soundarya, param Aishwarya, param gambhirya and other gunas

**लीलावताराः सन्ति अन्येऽल्पज्ञाश्चैव नराद्यः।
एको हि भगवान रामो मर्यादा पुरुषोत्तमः।**

(~#Shrimad_kaushik_ramayan)

There had been and will be many lila avtars of shri Vishnu (all avtars including narsimha,krishna, varah, vaman etc are lila purushottam) and also rishi, guru, humans were all less intelligent, but alone bhagwan shri Ramchandra is maryada purushottam.

श्री विष्णु के कई लीला अवतार हुए थे और होंगे (नरसिंह, कृष्ण, वराह, वामन आदि सभी अवतार लीला पुरुषोत्तम हैं) और ऋषि, गुरु, मनुष्य सभी कम बुद्धिमान थे, लेकिन केवल भगवान श्री रामचंद्र ही मर्यादा पुरुषोत्तम हैं

And even shri krishna admits

**तत्रास्ति मत्कारणमद्वितीयम् रामं परब्रह्म विशुद्ध बोधम्।
विधीश नारायण शेष पूर्वकम्, अहं च तं वर्णवितुं न शक्तः॥**

(Śrī Krishna Samhita 3.5, Lord Krishna to Shruti)

Once the Shruti's asked Lord Krishna, Lord! Tell me who is greater than you? Shri Krishna replied: My ultimate cause is the unique and pure Lord Sri Rama, to whom Brahma, Shankara, Narayana, Shesha and I are not able to describe.

So shri ram is paripurntam purushottam